# How to avoid the "Deceptive site ahead" screen on sites that host git pages?

Tags: github, web-hosting, securityexception

Browser shows this page while open my portfolio that I host in git hub

[image: error]

I have my portfolio hosted on GitHub and, when visiting webpage via URL, it shows security error (Deceptive site ahead).

Or more ref:

[image: error bis]

I have marked SSL on GitHub, I also tried without SSL and neither works.

**How can I avoid this security error?**

Answer (score 0):

You can see a similar case in [`abevoelker/how-long-since-google-said-a-google-drive-linux-client-is-coming` issue 2](https://github.com/abevoelker/how-long-since-google-said-a-google-drive-linux-client-is-coming/issues/2)

You would need to report your case to [`safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_general`](https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_general/)

> If you believe you've encountered an unsafe page where Google Safe Browsing should be displaying a warning but isn't, or a legitimate page where Safe Browsing is incorrectly displaying a warning, please complete the following form to notify the Safe Browsing team.